# Inserting and displaying data in <p> via jquery

Tags: jquery

i am making an onscreen keyboard and have created the list i can't add the functionality How to take input from a list element by a Jquery onclick function call and display it inside a paragraph within a div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<input id="textID" type="text">
<span id="add">Add</span>
<div id="result"></div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#result').append('<p>'+$('#textID').val()+'</p>');
    });
});
```

Comment: that's a pretty dumb way to do it, though. You'd need to use unique ID for each button, and add each listener separately.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a proper question, so I won't give a proper answer. Just the idea.

- Add a data attribute with the letter to each "key" button
- bind onClick to them all via jQuery
- each time the click handler is triggered, extract the letter from data, and append it to the "display" paragraph.